# Looking for the name of an orange crunchy snack

Tags: food-identification, snacks

The snack I'm talking about has an exterior similar to Chinese sweet and sour pork.

However, its shape is long and spindly. There is no meat in it. It is just the dough part. It is a bit sour and it is really sweet. It was sold in a box of the sweet. It is possibly Jewish or Arabic (I'm not certain about the letters I saw), I'm not sure. The texture is similar to the exterior of sweet and sour pork too, but it's only the outsider, doughy fried part.

The snack was encountered in Canada. It was long and looked kind of like a kebab without a stick and if all the pieces of meat were joined together. It definitely wasn't made of fruit though.

Jalebi (as mentioned in comments) just might be a possibilty. Whether or not it's really jalebi, it definitely looks similar to the food I'm thinking of. I will try it given the chance and update this.

Comment: I'm tempted to remove the image as it makes it look like you're trying to ID the food in the image, which isn't the case. I don't know if the image is really helpful to the question.

Comment: What country did you see this food in?

Comment: Candied fruit strips could possibly look like that.  Perhaps [candied papaya](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1296&bih=802&q=candied+papaya&oq=candied+papaya&gs_l=img.3..0j0i8i30k1j0i24k1l2.502.2153.0.2298.14.14.0.0.0.0.115.981.10j3.13.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..1.13.979...0i30k1j0i10i24k1.rZsnxXAs-Xk)?

Comment: Possibly a variation of [jalebi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jalebi) though it's more usually pretzel shaped in Indian sweet shops. Basically fried dough soaked in honey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed **[jalebi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jalebi)**. Everyone, go out to your local Indian eatery and try it out!